# JMeter "Summary Report" sum ones the get url and post url

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a service url same for GET and POST. And I am performing load testing using JMeter by adding HTTP Proxy Server to the WorkBench. I also added a listener "Summary Report" where we can see the attribute results.

When I test both urls for 20 threads/users then the #samples attributes shows 40 threads by the time it completes and there I can see only one url not two.

How can see the reports for both individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Transaction Controller with different name for each one.
This report will give you the information you want.

Comment: I just added a "Transaction Controller" on the HTTP Request.

Right clicked on the HTTP Request(URL) > "Insert Parent" > "Logic Controller" > "Transaction Controller". 
I did this for both urls and changed their names. And It WORKED!

Thank you so much!!